# Basic android with eclipse : the process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, eclipse

I have started doing some exercises from an android development book.
All i have done is

- create a project
- Input some code

  ```
  package com.wuhu.testapps;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class AndroidbasicsActivity extends ListActivity {
      String tests[] = {"LifeCycleTest", "SingleTouchTest","MultiTouchTest"};

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //setContentView(R.layout.main);
          setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tests));        
  }

      protected void onListItemClick( ListView list, View view, int position, long id)
  {    
      super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id );
      String testName = tests[position];
      try
      {
          Class clazz = Class.forName("com.wuhu.testapps." + testName);
          Intent intent = new Intent( this, clazz );
          startActivity(intent);
      }
      catch( ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Run as android application
- VM starts with activity in the background, but an error keeps appearing 'the process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly' Force close.

The first few lines of error in logcat are as follows :

```
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343): Cannot start provider
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343): java.lang.IllegalStateException: error upgrading the database to version 353
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsDatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(ContactsDatabaseHelper.java:1545)
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(ContactsDatabaseHelper.java:2550)
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
02-04 03:05:21.218: ERROR/ContactsProvider(343):  at com.android.providers.contacts.LegacyApiSupport.<init>(LegacyApiSupport.java:525)
```

Am not sure what is going wrong, can anyone help me?
Tried searching for an answer but to avail.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by the following method.

Android Virtual Device Manager > New

Remake Android Virtual Devices. Old setting delete.

Answer (score 1):

from Exception , it looks like sqlite cause this problem,  Anriod has Mechanism， It can auto update your database, if you override  onUpgrade method , just like the following:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
  db.execSQL(sql);
  onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your comment.
I am still getting the above mentioned error, even though i don't run any of the new code ( So i just start the VM with eclipse ).
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code. You should get the same error even if you virtual device directly.

Creating a new Virtual Device works well. Make sure to delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, Remove Comment from your below line.

`//setContentView(R.layout.main);` to  `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

and then try running again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not sure why that line was commented out, but uncommenting it didn't help. I have loaded another sample project from the SDK as well and am getting the error as well.. looks like a configuration problem maybe, any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thx for your comment. I am still getting the above mentioned error, even though i don't run any of the new code ( So i just start the VM with eclipse ). Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, have not been looking at this for a while, i found that the problem was that my target api and VM were mismatched.